# How can I play audio ( but secret url ) on WebSite? Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, web, html5-audio

I want to play an audio on WebSite but link of audio have to secret or encrypted on NodeJS

example: Spotify etc.

Comment: A) This question doesn't make enough sense to be able to answer it. B) You'll need to show us some code to demonstrate what you're trying to do. C) Anything the browser needs to know to stream music **will be visible to any sufficiently technically savvy user**. You cannot hide what the browser is doing.

Comment: Well, How does spotify do this?

Comment: In their desktop app or in the browser? If you're asking about in the browser then open your developer tools and have a look at what it does.

Comment: I'm talking about the browser. And I saw that there are no music files on Dev Tools. Or the <audio> tag on HTML

Comment: Keep looking. They're in there somewhere or you wouldn't hear anything. Look at the Network inspector.

Comment: There is nothing

Comment: Next step is tools like Wireshark to see what connections your browser is making and reverse-engineer this.

Comment: I just asked how I could do it, I wondered if there is a package or not. But Thanks :)

Comment: @MetecanKAPLAN have you tried sending audio over socket and play? this way your file URL will not be visible and still, you will get the file and will be able to play it.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to have your socket.io server which can send you an appropriate audio file for your request.

Once you are connected to socket sever send the name of the audio file to your server and the server will send the audio file over the socket. 
After receiving the file you can play as you want.
This way you will not expose the actual URL of the audio file because that is handled by your server.